# DynamoDB c# unable to update item with ADD operation on List

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have update operation that need to add new Map value to the List of maps in my Item.

```
        AttributeValue mapList = null;
        foreach (var item in purchasedItems)
        {
            mapList = new AttributeValue()
                { L = purchasedItems.Select(s => new AttributeValue() {M = s.ToAttributeMap()}).ToList()};
        }

        var response = await client.UpdateItemAsync(new UpdateItemRequest()
                {
                    TableName = Constants.Tables.PaymentData,
                    Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
                    {
                        {
                            Constants.Tables.GeneralColumnNames.PartitionKey,
                            new AttributeValue(id)
                        },
                        {Constants.Tables.GeneralColumnNames.SortKey, new AttributeValue(sortkey)}
                    },
                    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
                    {
                        {":purchasedItems", mapList}
                    },
                    UpdateExpression = "ADD PurchasedItems :purchasedItems"
                });
```

Here if I make Json of `mapList` it will give me:

```
    [
        {
            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
            "Price": 100,
            "CreatedAt": "2019-12-19T09:18:35",
            "Code": "123"
        },
        {
            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
            "Price": 100,
            "CreatedAt": "2019-12-19T09:18:35",
            "Code": "124"
        }
    ]
```

But this UpdateItemAsync throws

> Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBException: Invalid UpdateExpression:
>   Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: ADD,
>   operand type: LIST --->
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type
>   'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you looking to add new value in a list? You can use SET with list_append method. I dont know c# but I guess with this you can search the syntax.

Comment: I tried, but in C# it doesn't allow to define empty list in `ExpressionAttributeValues ` in case attribute is not in the item yet